# adding extra tags in xml launch files

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

we would like to add extra tags no supported by roslaunch to the launch xml files. these tags contain metadata that are very particular to the launch file, but do not fit into any of the current tag settings.

currently we get a warning  when we do this:

WARNING: unrecognized tag

however it is not clear what internal error flags roslaunch sets for this launch file, and wanted to make sure that such a feature is supported.

thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10022/adding-extra-tags-in-xml-launch-files/) by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 516 on 2011-05-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This feature isn't supported. I would use formatted comment markup, which is more the javadoc/doxygen/epydoc approach.

We could potentially support a generic metadata tag (filed as a feature request ticket); I wouldn't want to have arbitrary tag support as roslaunch is about have a clear model of the system launch.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having a generic metadata tag would help a lot, it would be sort of like the  tag in manifest.xml files. where would you like for me to file the ticket?

thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) on 2011-12-05**:
we updated the ticket with why we think this feature is valuable: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3515

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-31**:
Trac here:  https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/  . FYI: you can use 'post a comment' to reply to answers